# Get ActiveRecord results based on has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Toy and ToyPart ActiveRecord classes. Toy has_may ToyPart relationship.
The ToyPart ActiveRecord has a content field where the ToyPart is described and a type_desc field where very briefly describes ToyPart.

I need to get all Toy records based on content and type_desc fields from ToyPart. I did this statement to get th results:

```
Toy.all.to_a.toy_parts do {|toy_part| toy_part.where("content like (?) and type_desc='arm'", "%Left arm from%" }
```

This query takes too much time to return results. Toy table has more than 270000 records and each Toy has at least 5 ToyPart results.

I'm new to Ruby and on Rails. transform all record to an array I believe it's a huge process and doing another query in a loop the costs increases even more.

to_a is not a good idea. To alleviate processing what can I do to improve that?

P.S: I'm using rails 4.2.6.

Comment: Any search that has a "%something%" is going to be long.  What is happening in your code is that you are actually making this search over and over and over again making it really long.  Atul Khanduri's answer with joins means that you are only making 1 database hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `joins`? Something like this:

```
Toy.joins(:toy_parts).where("toy_parts.content like (?) AND toy_parts.type_desc='arm'", "%Left arm from%"")
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad it helped.